# WCF service using Json Bad Request

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I can not for the life of me figure out whats going on and who I can't post to my service using json. I've tried reading every comment under the sun from google on the issues I have but everything is currently bringing me to a dead end. Please help!

I pass the postback service off to a third party by a callback URL in a post to a service. The Third party then posts back in Json back to my wcf service using the call back url. I have no problem with the initial post but they and myself are not able to hit the callback service. I tried yet Fiddler returns a 400 error but i'm not sure why. I need a little more than web links and such to fix this problem. please help!

**Web.config file**

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="IBVWebService.InstantBankVerificationPostBack">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:64337/InstantBankVerificationPostBack.svc" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IBVWebService.IInstantBankVerificationPostBack"></endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Web Interface**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void PostBack(String json);
```

**Test Client**

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string jsonInput = "{'data':'testvalue'}";
        client.UploadString("http://localhost:64337/InstantBankVerificationPostBack.svc/PostBack", jsonInput);
```

**current trace log.**
[image: Tracelog]

Comment: Have you turned on WCF tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx to get more details about the error?

Comment: also configure `webBehavior` to include more details.

Comment: and consider that you're using `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`

Comment: So I've now got to the point where I get a post but its empty.

Comment: using fiddler with the following it gives me an null value for some reason.

Comment: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:64337
{"'data":"testvalue"}

Comment: The above comments are currently outdated and my code has somewhat changed. I have updated the post to reflect this change and the error i currently have.

Comment: Have you turned on WCF tracing as Rick said 2 days ago? Nothing beats WCF tracing

Comment: I have but im not getting anything from it currently. last update was Friday but since then i've kept looking for a solution and have changed it since then. current code is in the post above

Comment: never mind I had deleted the trace. here is the results from trace.

Comment: so changing the single quote to double quote on my example Gets to the method postback(string str) but str is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have replicated your scenario, with a simple wcf service with the configurations you have and a simple test client :

WCF

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void PostBack(String json);
```

Client :

```
string jsonInput = "{\"json\":\"testvalue\"}";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
     client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
     client.UploadString("http://localhost:51175/Service1.svc/PostBack", "POST", jsonInput); 
}
```

In the client make sure you match the signature of your WCF method, that is the object you are expecting is called *json*, so when you call the method from your client send **json:'value'**

Also, consider using a using statement for the webclient, to assure disposal after using it.

Comment: This answer is correct, I just verified it myself.  They key things to note are that you need to use double quotes in your json and that when you use WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, in this case, your property name in the json must match the parameter name of your method.

Comment: @KennethIto thanks for adding the info about `WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method parameter name is "json", so JSON input parameter should look like this :

```
string jsonInput = "{'json':'testvalue'}";
```